# Not able to remove the spaces between the rows of a dynamic grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Let me make this brief: I am building a webpage to draw a grid based on the rows and columns provided in the input value. When a user clicks the button, the input field values are to be fetched and the grid has to be drawn. I am unable to remove the space between the rows. ***Saw a lot of other questions on SO. None helped me sove this***

Below is a snapshot of my webpage:

[image]

And also, My wells aren't getting resized when I change my browser size. They run over the vertical line when the browser is shrinked.

So these are my questions:

1. How do I remove the spaces between the rows?
2. How do I make the wells responsive?
3. How do align the grid in the centre so that when the size is increased, its 
   growth focus must be from the center. Not the edge focus.

Clone my project: *https://github.com/gauravthantry/pixelArtMaker.git*

Below is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#grid-input").click(function() {
        $(".drawing-area").empty();

        var rows = $("#row").val();
        var cols = $("#col").val();
        if (rows > 0 && cols > 0) {

            for (var i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
                for (var j = 1; j <= cols; j++) {
                    $(".drawing-area").append('<canvas id="myPixel" width="20px" height="20px" style="border: 1px solid #000; "></canvas>');
                }
                $(".drawing-area").append('<br/>');
            }

        } else {
            alert("You haven't provided the grid size!");
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.page-position{
     background-image: url("https://i.pinimg.com/originals/f8/03/50/f8035042eda4eaeac4013e4f79ed85b2.jpg");
     width:100%;
     height: 100%;
}
 .content-position{
     background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
     margin-left: 20px;
     margin-right: 20px;
     margin-top: 20px;
     margin-bottom: 20px;
     border-radius: 2%;
     height: 600px;
     width: 96%;
     position: absolute;
}
 .heading{
     text-align: center;
     font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
     padding-top: 10px;
}
 .fa1{
     color: blue;
}
 .fa2{
     color: yellow;
}
 .fa3{
     color: green;
}
 .vertical-line{
     border-left: 1px solid white;
     height: 478px;
     margin-left: 30px;
}
 .color-option-container{
     width: 300px;
     background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
}
 .color-select{
}
 .grid-size-container{
     background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
     width: 300px;
}
 .text-line{
     border: none;
     border-bottom: 1px solid;
     width: 30%;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
     background: transparent;
}
 .rows{
     float: left;
}
 .cols{
     float: center;
     margin-left: 20px;
}
 .drawing-area{
     text-align: center;
     padding: 210px 0;
}
 .btn-size{
     text-align: center;
     width: 60px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>PIXEL ART MAKER</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="page-position">
    <!-- Content starts here -->
    <section class="content-position container-fluid">
        <section class="heading">
            <h1><i class="fa fa-fire-extinguisher fa1"></i> DRAW THE PIXELS</h1>
        </section>
        <hr>
        <section>
            <section class="row-fluid">
                <section class="col-xs-3">
                    <section class="well well-lg container-fluid color-option-container">
                        <form class="color-select">
                            <input type="radio" name="blue" value="blue" id="blue" checked><i class="fa fa-fire-extinguisher fa1"></i> BLUE
                            <br>
                            <input type="radio" name="yellow" value="yellow" id="yellow"><i class="fa fa-fire-extinguisher fa2"></i> &nbsp; YELLOW
                            <br>
                            <input type="radio" name="green" value="green" id="green"><i class="fa fa-fire-extinguisher fa3"></i> &nbsp; GREEN
                        </form>
                    </section>
                    <br>
                    <section class="well well-lg container-fluid grid-size-container">

                        <input type="text" class="text-line rows" id="row" placeholder="Rows">

                        <input type="text" class="text-line cols" id="col" placeholder="Cols">
                        <br/>

                        <button type="submit" class="btn-size btn btn-block btn-primary" id="grid-input"><i class="fa fa-th-large" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>

                    </section>

                </section>
                <section class="col-xs-1 vertical-line"></section>
                <section class="col-xs-6">
                    <section class="drawing-area">

                    </section>
                </section>
            </section>
        </section>
    </section>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: There is no `float: center;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `font-size:0` or `line-height:0` to the parent class `.drawing-area`

Also remove `width:300px` form your `.well` class
Also as mentioned in comments `float:center` is not valid value...so better to remove it

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#grid-input").click(function() {
    $(".drawing-area").empty();
    var rows = $("#row").val();
    var cols = $("#col").val();
    if (rows > 0 && cols > 0) {
      for (var i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
        for (var j = 1; j <= cols; j++) {
          $(".drawing-area").append('<canvas id="myPixel" width="20px" height="20px" style="border: 1px solid #000; "></canvas>');
        }
        $(".drawing-area").append('<br/>');
      }
    } else {
      alert("You haven't provided the grid size!");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.page-position {
  background-image: url("https://i.pinimg.com/originals/f8/03/50/f8035042eda4eaeac4013e4f79ed85b2.jpg");
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.content-position {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-radius: 2%;
  height: 600px;
  width: 96%;
  position: absolute;
}

.heading {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.fa1 {
  color: blue;
}

.fa2 {
  color: yellow;
}

.fa3 {
  color: green;
}

.vertical-line {
  border-left: 1px solid white;
  height: 478px;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.color-option-container {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}

.color-select {}

.grid-size-container {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  width: 300px;
}

.text-line {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  width: 30%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background: transparent;
}

.rows {
  float: left;
}

.cols {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.drawing-area {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 210px 0;
  font-size: 0;
}

.btn-size {
  text-align: center;
  width: 60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<body class="page-position">
  <!-- Content starts here -->
  <section class="content-position container-fluid">
    <section class="heading">
      <h1><i class="fa fa-fire-extinguisher fa1"></i> DRAW THE PIXELS</h1>
    </section>
    <hr>
    <section>
      <section class="row-fluid">
        <section class="col-xs-3">
          <section class="well well-lg container-fluid color-option-container">
            <form class="color-select">
              <input type="radio" name="blue" value="blue" id="blue" checked><i class="fa fa-fire-extinguisher fa1"></i> BLUE
              <br>
              <input type="radio" name="yellow" value="yellow" id="yellow"><i class="fa fa-fire-extinguisher fa2"></i> &nbsp; YELLOW
              <br>
              <input type="radio" name="green" value="green" id="green"><i class="fa fa-fire-extinguisher fa3"></i> &nbsp; GREEN
            </form>
          </section>
          <br>
          <section class="well well-lg container-fluid grid-size-container">
            <input type="text" class="text-line rows" id="row" placeholder="Rows">
            <input type="text" class="text-line cols" id="col" placeholder="Cols">
            <br/>
            <button type="submit" class="btn-size btn btn-block btn-primary" id="grid-input"><i class="fa fa-th-large" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
          </section>
        </section>
        <section class="col-xs-1 vertical-line"></section>
        <section class="col-xs-6">
          <section class="drawing-area"></section>
        </section>
      </section>
    </section>
  </section>
</body>
```

Comment: It worked. Could you also help me out in my 2nd and 3rd qustion. As you can see, when you run the code here, the well overflows the vertical line. How do I make it responsive so that it stays withing the vertical line.

Comment: @GauravThantry remove `width` from your `well`